# Trigger the Protractor test programmatically

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, testing, protractor, gulp-protractor

I am developing an application (angular7 and spring boot), which is web testing tool.
e.g. We need to create the Test script using the UI. Then, we can execute this script by just clicking on execute button with different technologies e.g. selenium, OATS, Protractor.

In this application I want to integrate the Protractor. I have created a config.js and spec.js file.
So, Issue I am facing are:

1. I need to trigger the execution programmatically.
2. Pass the parameter to the spec.js file

Solution I have tried:

1. I have created a new angular project. In which I have added config.js and spec.js. and tried running that from app.component.ts using following code.

```
const Launcher = require("protractor/built/launcher");
Launcher.init('path/to/conf');
```

But its not working. error is :

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
```

Can you suggest me any way?

Comment: try to look up a plugin that allows to inject CLI commands. And then you can do everything as you usually do

Comment: You could do something similar to the Protractor test directory. You could run the node command in a child process. 
https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/scripts/test.js and https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/scripts/test/test_util.js Is there a better way to do this? Maybe. Stay tuned, we'll announce something in 2021.

Comment: @cnishina That was great solution. Thanks So Much..